# Casting python list to cython ptr

Tags: python, casting, cython

For given ctype array or a python list, how does one cast python object to cython void ptr?

The way I'm doing it now is something like this(_arr is python list):

```
int *int_t = <int*> malloc(cython.sizeof(int) * len(_arr))
if int_t is NULL:
    raise MemoryError()
for i in xrange(len(_arr)):
    int_t[i] = _arr[i]
```

After this I have int_t, in which I have entire array. But I wan't the thing to be more general and support other types, not just int. Do I have to do the same thing for each type or is there any generic way in which this can be done?

Comment: Assuming you want the array to be filled with the same type of values, why not try writing an overloaded operator from C++, you'll have to have Cython compile to C++ instead, but that isn't hard. I'm not sure how to do that with classes defined in Cython though. If you want to fill it wit Python objects, I wouldn't recommend using an array like this at all. For some ideas on overloading, see http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#overloading .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that numpy arrays support [quite a range of data types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). Here is a general introduction on [how to work with numpy arrays in cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html). If you want to do numerical stuff that should do the trick. Also, numpy does support arrays of Python objects. But then again, the array lookups are optimized but interaction with the objects is not, since they are still Python objects.

If you are thinking about doing this with arbitrary types, i.e. converting arbitrary Python objects into some kind of C type or C++ object, you have to do it manually for every type. And this makes sense, too, since automatic casting between a potentially dynamic data structure and a static one is not always obvious, especially not to a compiler.